# Can a werewolf from another faction bite you?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-online

My friend has joined me in ESO and has become a werewolf, however he's in the Dominion whereas I'm in the Pact so there's a conflict of territories. He offered to bite me to allow me to become a werewolf but we're not sure how we'll be able to if he can't enter Pact territory. Is there a way around this so I can accept the werewolf bite?

Comment: Haven't played the game since beta, but isn't there the huge PVP area where everyone can enter? Depending on who owns which areas there you guys could probably meet relativly savely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Not playing the game anymore, but I guess my answer should be accurate. Please correct me if they changed it.*

## No, you can't be bitten by him

For biting another player, you will have to meet in "the one high level region" of **your faction**, where the Werewolf shrine is located. As players from other factions only meet in PvP areas, you both can't be in the same PvE area.

Comment: That is not entirely accurate. You can also be in the same pve area as a vet, but it will be different instances (unless you are really really lucky/unlucky).